# Transform complex series into power series and find its radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Determine the radius of convergence and find the coefficients of the power series which is equivalent to 
$$F(z) = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{z^n}{(1-z^n)^2}$$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

That is we would like to find such complex coefficients $a_1,a_2,...$ that $F(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n z^n$. Having those, we would find the radius from the Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Comment: For $|z|<1$ you have $\frac 1{1-z^n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{kn}$. Note that $F(z)$ is undefined for $z$ in a dense set of the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

The function $F$ is definitely analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb T$, where $\mathbb T$ denotes the unit circle. Since $\lim_{z\to 1}F(z)$ does not exist, $F$ cannot be extended. So, $F(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ for $|z|<1$. To obtain the $a_k$'s, note  that $\frac 1{1-z^n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{kn}$.

Comment: @metamorphy Did I say it's not?

Comment: @metamorphy No, I didn't. Please read more carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, the question states $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Sorry then ;)

Comment: @metamorphy so is it possible to find such coefficients for $|z|<1$?

Comment: @WojtekMaślakiewicz Yes, this is possible because $F$ is easily seen to be analytic in the unit disk.

Comment: @WojtekMaślakiewicz I have edited.